# Use Jquery Datepicker Instead of Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to use the Jquery Datepicker but it is not taking that up and using the bootstrap datepicker. I have found some answers but I am not able to implement that on my project and I am not able to understand that.
Here is the code

```
 $(function () {
        $('#txtDate').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay:
                function (dt) {
                    return [available(dt)];
                },
            changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, format: 'dd-MMM-yy'
        });
    });
```

The above code is suppose the run the JQuery Datepicker to give me the desired result but as it is working for the bootstrap datepicker it is not giving me the desired output.

I want to remove this conflict. How can I do that in my code. Any type of help or resources regarding this can really help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which bootstrap datepicker?

Comment: @cloned This one - https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: This does not come from bootstrap directly, it's just named bootstrap-datepicker. You can just remove it from your project if you don't need it. It is also very outdated, I wouldn't recommend using it at all.

Comment: @cloned I would have if I was allowed to.... I can't because the project is not mine alone.

Comment: Align with who is in the project which datepicker to use. It doesn't make sense to have two datepickers in one project. If they want to use the outdated bootstrap-datepicker then also use it for your datepickers.